# Cannot read property, variable undefined- Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I am trying to draw a bookshelf using an array of books and nested for loops. The for loops draw the book shelf, the book and title, and stars (ratings) for the book. However, while trying to access the stars variables I am getting a "stars undefined error". Any help is much appreciated.

```
var appsPerShelf = 4;

var apps = [
{title: "My House", author:"Claire", stars: 4},
{title: "My Animal":, author: "Claire", stars: 5},
{title: "Funny Face", author: "Claire", stars: 2},
{title: "My Inital", author: "Claire", stars:3},
{title: "Dancing Animals", author:"Claire", stars: 1},
{title: "Racing Animals", author:"Claire", stars: 5},
{title: "Resize Animal", author: "Claire", stars: 3},
{title: "App Bookshelf", author: "Claire",stars: 2},
{title: "Ball Follow App", author:"Claire", stars: 3},
{title: "Red Soz Quiz App", author:"Claire", stars: 5},
{title: "Zoo App", author:"Claire", stars: 4},
{title: "Dry Animal App", author:"Claire", stars: 5},
{title: "Dancing Animals Fun", author:"Claire", stars: 3},
{title: "Racing Animals Fun", author:"Claire", stars: 1},
{title: "Red Sox Quiz", author: "Claire", stars: 3}
];




//shelf drawer
for(var i=0; i<14%appsPerShelf; i++){
fill(173, 117, 33);
rect(0, 20+(20*i), width, 10);

//app drawer
for(var j=0; j<appsPerShelf; j++){
    fill(214, 255, 219);
    rect(10, 20, 90, 100);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text(apps[j].title, 15+(20*i), 19+(20*i), 70, 100); 

//star drawer
if(apps[i*appsPerShelf+j].stars){
for(var k=0; apps[i*appsPerShelf+j].stars; k++){
    var img = getImage("cute/Star");
    }}
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `Cannot read property 'stars' of undefined`?

Comment: yes! I don't if that is any different of a problem

Comment: Your question states `stars undefined error` whereas the actual problem is that the thing you're trying to access `stars` on is `undefined` (`apps[i*appsPersShelf+j]` resolves to `undefined` and so does not have any properties).

Comment: Yes, you can edit your question by clicking on 'edit' just underneath it, or [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45156073/edit).

Comment: You have got a typo here. `appsPersShelf` should be `appsPerShelf`. Note the extra `S`

Comment: Yes, you can either ensure that `apps[i*appsPersShelf+j]` is never `undefined` or assert that it is not `undefined` before attempting to access any properties attached to it (the former is the correct way to go about it).

Comment: this may sound dumb but how do I make sure apps[i*appsPersShelf+j] is never undefined?

Comment: You can either check it exists with `if (apps[i*appsPersShelf+j])` (or check the core variable with `if (appsPersShelf)`), or better yet, write it correctly as `apps[i*appsPerShelf+j]`. This is **just** a syntax error, and is therefor **off-topic** as a question.

Comment: I changed the syntax and added the if statement, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your line to this

```
for (var k = 0; k < apps[i * appsPerShelf + j].stars; k++)
```

e.g.

```js
var appsPerShelf = 4;

var apps = [{
    title: "My House",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 4
  },
  {
    title: "My Animal",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 5
  },
  {
    title: "Funny Face",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 2
  },
  {
    title: "My Inital",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 3
  },
  {
    title: "Dancing Animals",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Racing Animals",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 5
  },
  {
    title: "Resize Animal",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 3
  },
  {
    title: "App Bookshelf",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 2
  },
  {
    title: "Ball Follow App",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 3
  },
  {
    title: "Red Soz Quiz App",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 5
  },
  {
    title: "Zoo App",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 4
  },
  {
    title: "Dry Animal App",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 5
  },
  {
    title: "Dancing Animals Fun",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 3
  },
  {
    title: "Racing Animals Fun",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Red Sox Quiz",
    author: "Claire",
    stars: 3
  }
];

//shelf drawer
for (var i = 0; i < 14 % appsPerShelf; i++) {

  //app drawer
  for (var j = 0; j < appsPerShelf; j++) {
    console.log(apps[j].title);
    //star drawer
    var stars = "";
    for (var k = 0; k < apps[i * appsPerShelf + j].stars; k++) {
      stars += "*";
    }
    console.log(stars);
  }
}
```